# Creating simplified JSON from nested Json in Node JS

Tags: node.js, json

In NodeJS, I've JSON object as below

**Input JSON:**

```
  var myJSONObject = {
    "metadata": {
        "fields": {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "CUSTOMERID",
                    "type": "NUMBER(12,0)"
                },
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "CUSTOMERNAME",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ],
            "projections": [
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "ADDRESS",
                    "type": "string",
                },
                {
                  "kind": "COLUMN",
                  "name": "PHONE",
                  "type": "string",
              },
                
              ]
          }
        }
  }
```

I need to create a Simple JSON output as below from the above request.

**Expected Output JSON:**

```
{
    "projections": [
        "ADDRESS",
        "PHONE"
    ],
    "filters": [
        {
            "name": "CUSTOMERID",
            "type": "NUMBER(12,0)"
        },
        {
            "name": "CUSTOMERNAME",
            "type": "STRING"
        }
    ]
}
```

**My Code:**

```
          var result = {
            projections: [],
            filters: []
         };
          for(var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.metadata.fields.projections.length; i++)
          {  var name = myJSONObject.metadata.fields.projections[i].name;
              result.projections.push(name);
          }
          for(var i = 0; i < myJSONObject.metadata.fields.filters.length; i++)
          {  var name = myJSONObject.metadata.fields.filters[i].name;
             var type = myJSONObject.metadata.fields.filters[i].type;
             result.filters.push({name,type});
          }
          console.log(result)
```

**Actual Output:**

```
{
  projections: [ 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE' ],
  filters: [
    { name: 'CUSTOMERID', type: 'NUMBER(12,0)' },
    { name: 'CUSTOMERNAME', type: 'STRING' }
  ]
}
```

I've 2 questions, Please help !

1. Could you please me to achieve the expected output ( enclosed each key , values with double quotes) ?
2. Is there any better way to achieve this other than the above code

Comment: Important technical terminology note: there is no such thing as a "JSON array". only JS arrays on one side of the fence, and JSON (which is a single uninterrupted string) on the other. You create your JS data structure, and JSON.stringify turns that into JSON. If you need to change the structure of the _JS object_ represented by some JSON, your question isn't actually about JSON at all: it's a normal pure JS object question. So rephrase your problem: JSON parse/stringify are an afterthought, you just use them to get to/leave the JS side, where you do all the things you actually need to do =)

Comment: you have already arrived at the result you just have to use `JSON.stringify(result)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're allowed to use any `npm` libraries. But if you are and you want a bit simpler code, then I'll suggest you to use `json-find`. Here's what I did to make the code a bit simpler:

```
var JsonFind  = require('json-find');

var myJSONObject = {
    "metadata": {
        "fields": {
            "filters": [
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "CUSTOMERID",
                    "type": "NUMBER(12,0)"
                },
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "CUSTOMERNAME",
                    "type": "STRING"
                }
            ],
            "projections": [
                {
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "name": "ADDRESS",
                    "type": "string",
                },
                {
                  "kind": "COLUMN",
                  "name": "PHONE",
                  "type": "string",
              },

              ]
          }
        }
  }


var result = {
    projections: [],
    filters: []
 };

////////////////////////////////////////////

var doc = JsonFind(myJSONObject);

result.filters = doc.checkKey("filters");
var proj = doc.checkKey("projections");

for(p in proj){
    result.projections.push(proj[p].name);
    delete result.filters[p].kind;
}


console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
```

To have the double quotes, you just need to stringify the result.

Comment: This does not seem to work when the no of projections and filters differ.

Comment: Sure, it won't. I assumed they will same. If they're not, maybe you can use two loops of each. But still it would be simpler I guess